# creating scatterplot matrix using Plotly Dash in Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-dash

I have been searching for a couple of hours, but cannot find any example of scatterplot matrix using the Plotly **Dash** framework in python. (Using **Dash** and not Plotly create_scatterplotmatrix)

Can someone give me a simple example of a scatterplot matrix using **Dash** framework?

Comment: Scatterplot example is there on there [website](https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-drug-discovery/)

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? It will be great a sample of your df and an idea of the output you are looking for.

Comment: @PirateX I am looking for scatterplot matrix and not scatterplot. And of course sample, not visualization

Answer (score 1):

Dash uses Plot.ly to make its charts, so the Plot.ly documentation for charts is the same as Plot.ly's documentation.  The only separate documentation is about how to make webpages and use HTML components and callbacks.   You can look at Plotly's scatter plot documentation [Scatter Plots 2D](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/) [Scatter Plots 3D](https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/) to see how they are made. You can use the `Plotly Express` package which is part of dash to easily put your scatter plot into a Dash App:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/5d1ea79569ed194d432e56108a04d188/raw/a9f9e8076b837d541398e999dcbac2b2826a81f8/gdp-life-exp-2007.csv')

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdp per capita", y="life expectancy",
                 size="population", color="continent", hover_name="country",
                 log_x=True, size_max=60)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='life-exp-vs-gdp',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

As seen above you an just call `px.scatter(...)` and produce a scatter plot.  This example was taken from the Dash introduction documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/layout).  To see the output of a more advanced Dash scatter plot see the example from @PirateX.